# Demonstrating that particular Bernoulli and permutation events have the same probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I want to show that the following events have the same probability

- Throwing a coin $n$ times and getting $n/2$ heads.
- Choosing randomly a permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$ uniformly, with even number of cycles each of odd length.

The first is $\binom{n}{n/2}\frac{1}{2^n}$. From the second I do it by getting their combinatorial class, which is $Set_{\text{even}}(Cyc_{\text{odd}})$ with generating function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{x^{2k}}{4^{k}}$. So then I whould take $[x^n]$ from the aforementioned sum and divide it by the total cases, which are $(n-1)!$, but $[x^n]$ itself is equal to the probability, what doesn't have any sense because one is a rational number between $0$ and $1$, and the other is an integer.

The problem should be in the second equality that I stablished but I don't see any flaws. By the extended binomial theorem $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{-1/2}{k}(-1)^kx^{2k}$, where $\binom{-1/2}{k}=\frac{(-1/2)^{\underline{k}}}{k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{1\cdot3\cdot\ldots(2k-1)}{2^k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}$.

Just in case, $Cyc_{\text{odd}}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ and $Set_{\text{even}}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$. So doing composition we get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Comment: Please reformulate using some other summation index, avoiding the tacitly fixed (even) $n$.

Comment: @dan_fulea well, there is.

Comment: I realized all is right, what I wasn't seeing was that I what I need is $n![x^n]$ instead of $[x^n]$.

Comment: @UnPerrito. I answered your question on trees and the symbolic method. It has now been deleted before I could post.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel I thought no one was going to answer me. Would you send me your answer to my email (ecordenes@hotmail.com)? or do you prefer that I repost it? I will be grateful in both cases :)

Comment: @UnPerrito. I would prefer that you re-post it. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Done!

Comment: @UnPerrito I have proposed this sequence for inclusion at the OEIS. Would you like to provide your name as a co-author?

Answer (score 1):

You say that the total number of cases is $(n-1)!$, but the total number of cases is actually $n!$, since you are randomly choosing a permutation of $[n]$.

Letting $a_n$ be the number of permutations with an even number of cycles all with odd length, then you found the exponential generating function of $a_n$ to be $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$, which means that $[x^n](1-x^2)^{-1/2}=a_n/n!$. Note $a_n/n!$ is exactly the probability of getting one of these special permutations. Furthermore, $[x^n](1-x^2)^{-1/2}=\binom{n}{n/2}2^{-n}$ whenever $n$ is even, so this agrees with the coin flipping probability.

Does this answer your question? If not, can you clarify what you are confused about? All the math in your post is 100% accurate, so I am confused about where you are confused.

Comment: Actually, I have realized that error but I didn't edited here the text, and as I said in the comments, I realized that my main confusion was that in a FGE the $n!$ under $x^n$ is not part of the counting sequence. Haha. Anyways, thanks for reading me, and I really apologize for quit your time =(!